# Azure Data Factory Schedule Trigger Different environment settings

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In Data Factory I'm using the DevOps pipeline to deploy my changes from Dev to UAT or Production. I have a Scheduled Trigger in my Data Factory that runs every day, and in my Dev environment, the status of my trigger is Stop and when I deploy the adf_publish I want the schedule trigger to be started in the UAT or Prod environment. Is there's a way to do this? I only rely on adf_publish.

Answer (score 1):

Using your post deployment PowerShell script (assuming you use that approach) you can start the trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/start-azdatafactoryv2trigger.

/MMT

Comment: Currently the post deployment script provided in the docs assumes state is the same in PROD And DEV, but its  a pretty quick change to ensure your triggers are started